# How to convert python integers into c integers?

Tags: python, c

How tThere are many threads about going from a [c](/questions/tagged/c) language integer to [python](/questions/tagged/python) integer, but none that i can find vice versa. I am using a native c library, `opengl`, ported into python `pyopengl`.

Annoyingly all the functions require c variable data types. my question is simple how do I give a function a c language type integer as an argument for that function. i have tried the `ctypes` library with the following code:

```py
import ctypes
    
integer = 0
cinteger = ctypes.c_int(int)

print(cinteger)
```

```
output: c_long(0)
```

The problem is that for some reason all `c_int` functions return a 64bit long which `pyopengl` does not accept.

I cant seem to find a good tutorial on `ctypes` library for this specific use case. I would prefer to avoid  using class objects unless necessary, since i only need one c integer value.

I have also tried python `bin()` method to try and replicate the 32bit binary equivalent of a c integer but i cant get my head around it.

edit:
just for some context here is the function i want to call:

```
shader = """                 #just some code i need for the library to work
insert c code here
int texture
"""
pointer = glgetattriblocation("texture",shader) #returns a ctype integer
glUnifrorm1i(pointer,integer value)  #here is my real problem, because for 
# this integer value i cant just do glgetattriblocation which would give me   
# an error and also because it is a pointer to my data and the int is the
# data that i want to pass, therefore i need a 4 byte int following the same 
# convention as the c language for this function to work.
```

Comment: Try using `c_short`.

Comment: Have you tried using `ctypes.c_uint32` (or `ctypes.c_int32`)?

Comment: thanks alot for the suggestions, regarding ctypes.c_uint32, how would i get say integer 1? would  i just do ctypes.c_uint32(1)?#

Comment: tried c_short which outputs a 2 byte short doesn't work. uint32 and int32 both give 8 byte longs instead of the 4 byte c integer that i need.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem.  Can you show a [mcve] attempting to do what you want?  Make sure it is standalone code that reproduces the problem, has all needed imports, etc.  Are the imports all available on PyPI?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest using the python [struct library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html).

```
from struct import *
struct('i', 66)

b'B\x00\x00\x00'
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings
Read up on how to format you data types.

Comment: The second line is wrong (did you mean `pack`?), and you have not explained what this does. Why would passing this structured binary data do what is needed for passing data to DLLs?